# Usage of articles for animals

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

While I was reading my grammar book I found below sentences with explanations:

> 1) **A Cow** is a useful Animal.
>
> 2)**The Dog** is a faithful animal.

I don’t know why “A cow” is used and why “The dog” is used. 1) Can’t they just be “Cow is a useful animal” ,  “Dog is a faithful animal”??

2)What is the difference in meaning when articles “a/an” and “the” before name of animal (I mean difference between “A cow” and “the cow”)

Comment: The definite article is normally used when referring to that species of animal in general (so 'The cow is a useful animal' would be correct as well).

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/208040/the-cow-or-a-cow-or-cows-in-this-context?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The cow" OR "a cow" OR "cows" in this context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/208040/the-cow-or-a-cow-or-cows-in-this-context)

Answer (score 3):

As I'm sure you know, the definite article "the" is used to refer to something *specific*. So in many contexts, you would say "*the* cow" about a specific cow, and "a cow" if speaking generally about any particular cow, or a cow you couldn't specifically identify (eg "what's a cow doing in my garden?")

However, we sometimes use the definite article with the name of an animal to refer to *the entire species*. Just look up any animal *species* on Wikipedia - for example "***The*** Humpback Whale is a species of baleen whale".

However, while it isn't incorrect to say "the cow" or "the dog" to refer to them as a collective, cows and dogs are not *generally* spoken of in such terms, possibly because, as domestic animals, they are both broader terms which can be further broken down into different *breeds*. You are more likely to hear "the Alsatian" or "the Highland" to refer to specific breeds of dogs or cows.