# Every noun is unique?

Tags: articles

Can we use the definite article the before every noun before defining as the  noun will be unique like "The cow is a useful animal" etc instead of "A cow is a useful animal" because the noun cow is unique?

Comment: This is a duplicate and uniqueness has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I don't know why the duplicate I put in the close message did not pop up here. Here it is: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22647/uses-of-the-definite-article-the-in-generic-noun-phrases

Comment: See also [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/208040/the-cow-or-a-cow-or-cows-in-this-context?rq=1).